# Windows Universal App 8.1 Custom User Control

Tags: c#, windows, windows-runtime, windows-phone

For the past two weeks, I have a problem which I cannot resolve. Believe me, I have been looking for answers all over the internet without finding any solution let alone hints.

I am currently working on a Windows 8.1 Universal App. I have developed a pattern lock control (control A) similar to the one known from android devices. The control is composed of 9 *points* which are represented by instances of a different control (control B). Control A as well as controls B have their own dependency properties. Some of which have concrete values (e.g. **StrokeBrushThickness="2"**) while others have a value that is defined within the app resources (e.g. Brushes).

The problem I am facing is that everything works well for the Windows Phone project. However, when I reference control A inside the Windows project I receive following XAML error for the A's dependency properties that have concrete values:

> Unknown error: Cannot find a resource with the given key.

If I remove the aforementioned properties from the control, the app compiles but throws a *Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException* during runtime:

> WinRT-Informationen: Failed to assign to property < PROPERTY NAME >

Moreover, I get the following XAML error for a some resources I have defined within the app, e.g.:

```
<Color x:Key="ColorBackground">#F4F2F4</Color>
<SolidColorBrush x:Key="AppBackgroundBrush" Color="{ThemeResource ColorBackground}"/>
```

I can sort of get the whole thing to work if I remove control A and place the point controls (B) directly into a grid. However, I hope to avoid this workaround as you can image control A encapsulates a lot of functionality that is needed repeatedly across the app.

I hope I have made myself clear. If not, I'll be more than happy to provide further information.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you always use `ThemeResource`? If so do you place your resources in `ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries`?

Comment: I tried it both ways - using `ThemeResource` as well as StaticResource. It doesn't seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have failed to register your dependency properties correctly.
Check the parameters you pass to `DependencyProperty.Register` method.

Probably you throw an exception from your property changed callback, you shouldn't do that.

P.S. It is sometimes easier to use Expression Blend to edit those XAMLs. You will spend some time learning, the tool is not targeted towards programmers; it is for designers, so the user experience is completely different. However, if you will invest some time, it is very unlikely you will ever face problems like “Cannot find a resource with the given key”.

Comment: I registered my Dependency Properties this way: `public static readonly DependencyProperty StrokeBrushProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("StrokeBrush", typeof(Brush), typeof(PatternLockControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));` I never throw any exceptions from within the property changed callback.